# Whitelist/Filter incoming ips for https load balancer

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, whitelist, google-compute-engine

I use Google Container Engine with Kubernetes.
I have created an https load balancer which terminates ssl and forwards traffic to k8s cluster nodes. The problem is I see no option to whitelist/filter incoming ip addresses. Is there any?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you've set up a load balancer outside of Kubernetes. You may want to consider using a Kubernetes `Service` set to `type: LoadBalancer`. That type of service will give you an external IP that load balances to all of your `Pods` and can be easily restricted to whitelist IPs using the `loadBalancerSourceRanges` setting. Here is the example from the docs at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
ports:
    - port: 8765
      targetPort: 9376
  selector:
    app: example
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 79.78.77.76
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 130.211.204.1/32
  - 130.211.204.2/32
```

Comment: This creates on GCP a tcp load balancer with random ephemeral IP (but I need to use a static one), and I'll have to do ssl termination/key management by myself...

Comment: On GCP you can use `loadBalancerIP` to specify a pre-created static IP. Updated the example to include that. You are correct though that you'll need to terminate the SSL using something inside Kubernetes (usually using an Ingress controller https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but too much changes for us, we'll wait for GCP team to implement the feature. So far I ended up implementing own ip filtering based on x-forwarded-for headers

Answer (score 1):

If you're using gce controller is not yet possible[1], just nginx controller[2] accept whitelist ip.

[1] https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/issues/566

[2] https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/188c64aaac17ef29400e0f143b9aed7770e32fee/controllers/nginx/configuration.md#whitelist-source-range